# OptionButton Property Disable

Tags: vba, ms-access, radio-button

I have an option group or "frame", and inside I have 4 buttons (Option Buttons).

They are called:

opt_mtto
opt_elec
opt_qlty
opt_complete

So I was selecting the property of each button to Enable = False, so when my form load they will be Disabled. But, I didn't to be coding each button to enable each of the buttons, I though.. why wouldn't be better to say to the frame to be disable, so all inside would be disable.

So instead of going for each button, I return to my properties and enabled them again, but I disable my frame, so this made the same way, but only with 1 click .

But I got a problem, when I click a button I want my frame get enabled so I code:

```
frame01.enabled = True
```

(This enabled all my buttons..)

But I only want 1 button Disable, in this case:

```
opt_mtto.enabled = false
```

so my code is:

```
frame01.enabled = true
opt_mtto.enabled = false
```

and this get me an error: 2101: "The setting you entered isn't valid for this property".

So I made this the other way, I enabled my frame, and then call the option button to be disable, and it works...

I only want to know why, I can't do this, the first way I mention.

I repeat is:

- When Form_Load the property are already set to the frame as False (no CODE, is set manually, in properties)
- When click button, enable Frame,
- Just after of enable the frame, disable one of the buttons inside.
- ERROR...

Why

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

The frame was getting focus before disabled the button.

You can't disable controls if they are focus, this wasn't the same case, because the focus was on the frame, not in the button, but it happened the same way, I just needed to re-focus in other place.